# Mobonacci - Fibonacci manipulation in Assembly Code

Tags: assembly, recursion, masm, fibonacci, irvine32

Hi guys I have been working on this assignment and struggling. It is a remake of the the fib sequence the changes are that it goes f(n-2)/2+f(n-1)*2 and the starting two numbers are 1 and 2 so some of the sequence would be as follows. 1,2,4,9,20,44,98. We are to complete the multiplication and division using shift left and shift right (shl and shr) I feel like I am very close but my code for some reason will not read in a number that is over the value of 2 or at least that's how I am seeing it. If you could look and give me some direction on what could be causing this whether it be my actual formula part or the before and after thank you. The very first main is my simple way of just spewing out the result.

```
 include Irvine32.inc

.code
main PROC
    push 1
    call fib
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf
    push 2
    call fib
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf
    push 3
    call fib
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf
    push 4
    call fib
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf
    push 5
    call fib
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf
    push 7
    call fib
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf
  exit
main ENDP

fib PROC 
   push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov ebx, [ebp+8] ;get number to calc that was pushed before 

    ; if ((n == 1) || (n == 0)) return 1;
   mov eax,1
   cmp ebx,1
   jle Quit


    ;else return fib(n-2)/2 + fib(n-1)*2;


    valid:

    ;(n-2)/2
   dec ebx ;n-1
   dec ebx ; n-1 again so n-2
   push ebx  ; store the number
   call fib  ; calculate n-2
   shr ebx,1 ;(n-2)/2
   push eax  ;store it away
   mov ebx, [ebp+8] ;get number to calc

   ;(n-1)*2
   dec ebx ;(n-1)
   push ebx ;store the numebr
   call fib ;calculate n-1
    shl ebx,1 ;(n-1)*2
    pop edx ;bring back the (n-2)*2 saved value
    add eax,edx ;adds the n-2 and n-1 together
   jmp Quit 





Quit:
   pop ebp  ;return base pointer
        ret 4  ;clean stack
fib ENDP

END main
```

Comment: What do you mean by, *will not read in a number that is over the value of 2*? What exactly are you seeing?

Comment: Also, I would recommend reading carefully through your `fib` routine. Take a pen and paper and walk through it and see what happens.It has several fundamental errors which, if you examine it closely enough, you should be able to discover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate f(n-2)/2 you need to use SHR in stead of SHL.

```
;(n-2)/2
sub ebx,2
shr ebx,1
```

To calculate f(n-1)*2 you need to use SHL in stead of SHR.

```
;(n-1)*2
dec ebx
shl ebx,1
```

Why don't you simplify the code? (You don't need the code at *ReturnFib*.)

```
; if ((n == 1) || (n == 2)) return 1;
 mov eax, 1   ;less than 3 so result is 1, no need to calculate Fibonacci
 cmp ebx, 2
 jle Quit
valid:
```

EDIT

Here's how it looks for the first term.

```
;f(n-2)/2
sub ebx,2
push ebx  ; store the number
call fib  ; calculate n-2
shr eax,1
push eax  ;store it away
```

Comment: Thanks for your help guys I looked through and made the changes where i am at now is that it prints out 1 then 1 again and then goes endless

Comment: I think the problem is in my initial if n=1 or n=2 statement the more i change that around the more different results i get

Comment: That's because you did not understand the exercise! You've implemented **f((n-2)/2)+f((n-1)*2)**. Look closely at the brackets!

Comment: How do I drop the extra bracket? Do I have to move my shift left and shift right commands up more?

Comment: See the EDIT in my answer.

Comment: Okay I changed bot of my shifts it now runs without an endless loop but instead of doing "mobanacci" it is actally somehow still doing the correct fibonacci sequence

Comment: I actually just saw you have changed the shift right to eax and I did that and now it outputs all 1's

Comment: Make sure to change the second term and do the addition. (result is 1,1,2,4,9,...)

Comment: What do you mean second term? And I do the addition with adding eax to edx did I accidently mess that up? What you have in parenthesis is correct other than the 1,1 its supposed to be 1,2 I do not get what you have unfortunately. Hey I really appreciate all your help man and the quick responses thanks for working with me

Comment: How could you expect a sequence like **1,2** if you code  **if ((n == 1) || (n == 2)) return 1**? This always returns **1,1**

Comment: The second term is **f(n-1)*2** Calculate it similarly to the first term and then add.

Comment: I tried to change the code to just return 1 when its 1 and I understand the second term I thought my code was correct?

Comment: Better use **if ((n==0) || (n=1)) return 1**.  Please make an EDIT below your question with the revised code but make sure to not change the original contents of the question!!!

Comment: Would I really even need it if I just had it go through.my valid loop? It should output the same thing right?

Comment: No, you definitly need 2 values with a fixed return otherwise the recursion will hang.

Comment: Okay I'll check it out I just stepped out I'll post in a little

Comment: So i made the edit and changed my if n==0 but i still get a wrong output i got 1,2,3,5,8 instead if 1,2,4,9

Comment: Your edited code looks fine BUT after both recursive calls to FIB the result is in EAX and thus your SHL/SHR must be done on EAX!!!